# Parameterized constructor in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

Can I declare parameterized constructor inside servlet which is only constructor ?

If no then why ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Servlet instances are created by the container via reflection, and they expect to find a public, no-arg constructor (the default constructor).

To configure your servlet, use servlet parameters specified in the web.xml file. These are passed to your servlet's [`init()`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init(javax.servlet.ServletConfig)) method.

---

While it would be *possible* for a servlet container to choose a non-default constructor and coerce character strings to simple types and invoke the constructor reflectively, this isn't what the Servlet specification requires.

Part of the reason may be historical; servlets were first specified long before dependency injection systems made this alternative widely practiced. However, such constructors would be fairly limited; it would be practical to pass arguments that can be created from a simple character string specified in the web.xml, but more useful objects—a `DataSource`, for example—would be awkward.

It would be nice to have final member variables in a servlet though.

The JSR formerly known as "WebBeans" (JSR 299, I think), will provide some standards for dependency injection support in Servlets. This might address some of the drawbacks in the current approach.

Comment: But why it is expecting default constructor ? We can invoke parameterized constructor also using reflection.

Comment: Then how will it know, what values to pass in the constructor?

Comment: Have you had a look at what Servlet 3.0 provides yet?

Answer (score 1):

Since servlets are instantiated by the container they need a no-argument constructor.

Additionally the container may reuse servlets and will not call the constructor on reuse.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to initialize the variables through `<servlet-param>` or use a Framework like Spring which can allow you to Proxy the Servlet to a different class that acts just like any other bean.

Answer (score 1):

no! we cannot provide a parameterized constructor in servlet.The servlet container creates the
object for sevrlet.The container will create the object based on `Class.forName(String classname)`. we can create an object to a class  using `Class.forName()`, if the class contains default constructor only.since the container uses the `Class.forName()` code in creating object, we do not write parameterized constructor as part out servlet. Even though if we want to write parameterized constructor, we have call the constructor from `service()`method!