# Servlets - use constructor or not?

Tags: servlets, coding-style, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, servlet-3.0

Constructors in servlets is considered a good/bad practice ? How does it compare to the `init()` method ? Using servlet-3 and vanilla javaEE (CDI provided by javax.inject package)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in using constructors in servlets. The reason to switch to `init()` is when you need to obtain `ServletConfig`, `ServletContext`, etc. These objects might not be available (yet) in constructor.

Also *hypothetically* some containers might do fancy things with servlets like dynamic subclassing or proxying. Finally side-effects in constructors tend to make testing harder.

To avoid unexpected behaviour and make sure your servlets are 100% portable just stick with `init()`. Also if you use `destroy()` as well, implementing `init()` will make your code more "*symmetric*".

## See also

- [Parameterized constructor in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945778)
- [How to initialize a Servlet during startup with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276082/constructor-in-servlet/2659597#2659597)
- [why we can't initialize a servlet using constructor itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920616)

Comment: I guess then first `init()` is called then the constructor ? Also could you elaborate on _side-effects_ ? Also is there a case a Servlet constructor may be required (in the context of a famework for instance) ? Finally could you provide some links (however technical) - especially on the way init() happens behind the scenes ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: 1. no, no method can be called on an object prior to constructor, including `init()` 2. Read about mocking and proxying - in some circumstances constructor can be called twice. 3. See the link I added to my answer, servlet *must* have a no-arg constructor. 4. Guess it's container-dependant. All you need to know is that it's called after constructor and before any `service()` call.

Comment: 1.Yes - sorry. 3. This can be the default constructor - I do not have to write one - right ? Another link on the subject from SO  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276082/constructor-in-servlet/2659597#2659597)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: Ad 3. There **must** be a no-arg constructor - either the one you wrote or the default one created by the compiler for you.

Answer (score 0):

yup we can have constructor in servlets but it is not required bcoz-

servlets are initialized by the web container. servlets is not initialized unlike other java class. Constructor are used to initialize an explicitly created object while servlet use a different method 'init()' for their initialization.

Servlet is only an interface(javax.servlet.Servlet) and interface in java dont have any constructor and a construcor of an implementing class cant declare in the servlet interface and it doesn't make any sense. Container will only use the init() method to initialize the servlet.

Comment: and ya we need init method bcz to initialize servlet we require special object servletConfig and we can have access to this object in init method only not in constructor.